# Item Protected issue when sending email from EXM newsletter

Tags: exm

Need help in fixing the below issue.

When we are trying to send an email form EXM “DELIVERY” tab, Email Campaign Message Item (The item which create under the path /sitecore/content/Email Campaign/Messages ) is getting Protected automatically.

You cannot edit this item because it is protected.
To unprotect the item, click Unprotect Item on the Configure tab or click Unprotect Item.

Because of this protection unable to send an email from EXM.

When I remove the Item Protection of Message Item which exists under (Ex: Path: /sitecore/content/Email Campaign/Messages/2018/09/03T134033) then we are able to send an email without any issues.

Thank you for the help in advance:)

Comment: It's getting protected by design. Once dispatch of an email campaign has started, it's not expected to be edited.

Which version of Sitecore and EXM is this? Do you see any errors in the log files - Sitecore log file, and EXM + EDS log files? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hello, I got the hotfix for this issue. Refer https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/xd7o60jxhp2t1dkucf7sbp00trcke966

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue when using the "Duplicate Campaign" method on an already dispatched regular email message, on a currently activated Automated message, which in both cases are because the duplicate method is simply copying the Sitecore Message item. If the message item has a lock on it already, it appears that it does not unlock the item.

The EXM UI will alert you that the item is protected and provide you a way to unlock the item right then and there.

I consider this a "by-design" characteristic of EXM.

Comment: Finally we got a solution for this

Comment: Please use the link below to download patch and install it.
https://sitecore.app.box.com/s/xd7o60jxhp2t1dkucf7sbp00trcke966 
The patch adds a possibility to change that timeout. Set to 1 minute and try, if it doesn’t work try to increasing value or set it to 0: <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.Deployment.Processors.Deploy, Sitecore.Analytics"
                   set:type="Sitecore.Support.Analytics.Reporting.DefinitionData.Marketing.Deployment.Processors.Deploy, Sitecore.Support.116539">
   <param desc="timeout">00:01:00</param>
  </processor>